# ColdFusion Encrypt with Salt + Iterations, not working

Tags: encryption, coldfusion

Here is the function, with variable names in place

```
encrypt(arguments.input, key, algorithm, encoding, arguments.salt, iterations)
```

I'm using a 256 bit AES key which is 44 characters long.

I am choosing `AES` and `base64` for Algorithm and Encoding.

I've tried various ways of generating a salt, 
`createUUID()`, `generatesecretkey('AES',128)` and `generatesecretkey('AES',256)`

The encrypted result is always the same with the same input, when the salt changes each time. Like it's ignoring it, there is no error to suggest why.

I also note, iterations has no effect on the encryption either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm "AES" is actually [shorthand for "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/strong-encryption-coldfusion-mx-7.html) (ie algorithm/mode/padding). When using the default [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#ECB), the `iv` will be ignored. Use the longhand algorithm form to specify CBC mode, ie "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"

**[Runnable Example on Trycf.com](http://trycf.com/gist/db2f598dcd3d509f27e209240f055328/acf?theme=monokai):**

```
<cfscript>
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    key = "ji3fd0ZKB87COPz5ZwqsQEQKcuRggtvvO98t3mZFxns=";
    // generate different iv's for DEMO only
    uuid = CreateUUID();
    iv = BinaryDecode( replace(uuid, "-", "", "all"), "hex");

    input = "This is plain text to be encrypted";
    encoding = "base64";
    algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    encrypted = encrypt(input, key, algorithm, encoding, iv);
    decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key, algorithm, encoding, iv);

    writeOutput("<hr>["& i &"] encrypted="& encrypted );
    writeOutput("<br>["& i &"] decrypted="& decrypted );
    writeOutput("<br>["& i &"] iv="& uuid );
}
</cfscript>
```

*Note: To use larger keys, like 256bit, you must first have installed the [(JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html)*

Comment: Thank you, the shorthand key 'AES' was the issue. Which also highlighted my new issue with the IV - fixed!

Comment: The documentation you point to is much better, to bad there was no link to it in the base documentation.

Comment: @Zaph - I know, right? I remember struggling with encrypt and searching the javadocs (which CF's encrypt is based on) for a while before finding that article. A simple link would have been a great help ;-)

Comment: @leigh do you know how i should store the salt in oracle, I tried creating it as RAW, but get the error "ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings", tried it without quotation marks in the SQL insert too, like as a number.

Comment: @DanielCook - I do not use Oracle much. If the "raw" type is used for binary try using cfqueryparam with one of the binary cfsqltypes. This old [cfqueryparam matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) suggests using `CF_SQL_VARBINARY`.

Answer (score 2):

AES only supports three key lengths, 16, 24 and 32 bytes. Note that 44 characters is 352-bits which is none of these. But it appears that the encrypt method expects a Base64 encoded string as the key so a 44 character Base64 key would seems to be correct. The documentation does not detail the key form.

Also note that the iv (`arguments.salt`) must be **exactly** one block in size, for AES that is 16-bytes.

See [Encrypt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c2f.html) for more information.

For more help please supply the encrypt arguments and the result.

Comment: If I run generatesecretkey('AES',256) I get a 44 character string, for example - ji3fd0ZKB87COPz5ZwqsQEQKcuRggtvvO98t3mZFxns= If what you say is true, where have I gone wrong.

Comment: Also http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45318/how-long-in-letters-are-encryption-keys-for-aes 'An AES 256-bit key can be expressed as a hexadecimal string with 64 characters. It will require 44 characters in base64.'

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is not clear on detains, I guess the generation method produced a Base64 string and encrypt expects a Base64 string. Encryption is byte based, not character based and languages that only support characters are a problem. What about the iv?

Comment: *the documentation is not clear on details* Yes, [this article on String Encryption in CF](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/strong-encryption-coldfusion-mx-7.html) provides much more details. (Ignore the outdated version number, the concepts still apply).

Comment: Thanks for your help Zaph, the actual issue has been highlighted by Leigh. But you were right about the salt size being 16-bytes